# How to charge for web maintenance services

Tags: site-maintenance

Over the years we have developed many websites for clients.

The issue we currently deal with is having individual clients wanting minor changes or enhancements to their site. Each client doesn't contact us often, but collectively this adds up into a bunch work.

To date we don't have a clean way to charge for these services, and as a result it often seems easier to do a quick fix and in fact much of this work goes unbilled as it just seems to hard.

Please outline what you consider to be a better system to handle these clients, links to any maintenance agreements.

I considered the idea of charging clients for prepaid block hours of say 10 hours and then when they make requests we can just draw down from that, but we don't know of any good systems which already do this kind of thing.

What should we do?

Answer (score 1):

I've seen several versions when working with firms that handle websites.

1. small monthly maintenance fee
2. prepaid blocks of time at a discount
3. hourly rate sheet w/ or w/o minimum (typically 2 hours)

Answer (score 1):

I offer two service contracts: 30 minutes a month for $1X or 90 minutes for $2X. Most clients don't use all of their time so I can price slightly below my normal rate and be OK.  Additional hours are discounted from my regular hourly, if they commit to a contract.  This is only for fixes or changes, new development is at standard rate.